# Htaccess not getting 'GET' variables even with QSA flags

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I can't seem to get my 'GET' variables passing through with my htaccess code. Here it is below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ v.php?shareid=$1&filename=$2 [QSA, L]
</IfModule>
```

I have `v.php` in the root, not in any folder and I am trying to achieve the following URL:

```
http://localhost/v/ubgvfmrsazwxoyp/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-05%20at%2020.51.45.png
```

where `ubgvfmrsazwxoyp` is the shareid and `Screen%20Shot%202015-11-05%20at%2020.51.45.png` the file name.

None are getting registered when page is loaded.
**Note:** I also want to keep .php extensions hidden.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make .htaccess pass all GET parameters without knowing what they are named?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072033/how-do-you-make-htaccess-pass-all-get-parameters-without-knowing-what-they-are)

Comment: @zod No. This question is not a duplicate of the linked one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^v/([^/]+)/(.*)/?$ v.php?shareid=$1&filename=$2 [L]
```

You were previously getting `v` as the `shareid` and `ubgvfmrsazwxoyp` as the filename.

**NOTE**: The above code is specifically for an [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess) file inside the server root directory. If the rewrite rules are going in the vhost config or the server config file, you'll need to use:

```
RewriteRule ^/v/([^/]+)/(.*)/?$ v.php?shareid=$1&filename=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it probably works but htaccess is acting up on me with my localhost config. Will give it a try later on with normal hosting. Cheers.