# How to send $_GET values with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to send an id to an other page using GET. I'm using a script that someone else build. The usual `http://<site>/<page>?id=1` doesn't work.

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([0-9]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([0-9]+)([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&p=$2&del [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the query string is not passed when being run through the above rewrite rules.

So following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5072087/1824988) I suggest you try to add `QSA` to all of the rules, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([0-9]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([0-9]+)([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&p=$2&del [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear
edit the question if U want someone answer U.

as I understand from your question U want to pass values form page to another in php
it s ok like this

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>
       <form action="index.php" method="get">
         <input name="value" type="text">
         <input name="submit" type="supmit">
       <form>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

index.php

```
 if(isset($_GET['submit']){
 echo $_GET['value'];
 // or do something using the values got
}
```