# GET parameter doesn't work with htaccess rules

Tags: .htaccess

So, I have this code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Every file loses its extension (/index.php -> /index etc) and that works perfectly fine. But later on, I started working with admin panel and I'm using some GET parameters there. For example, problematic URL look like:

```
example.com/admin?cat=1
```

As far as I know, RewriteRule gets only string after RewriteBase and is not catching GET parameters, right? So why when I try to go to this URL it rewrites it to this?

```
http://example.com/C:/OpenServer/domains/example.com/admin/1/
```

---

*There is also this line in .htaccess(but doesn't look like there is problem with it):*

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin.php?cat=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072033/how-do-you-make-htaccess-pass-all-get-parameters-without-knowing-what-they-are), you have to add `[QSA]` at the end of your `RewriteRule` line:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA]
```

Google search query that lead me to that answer: `htaccess pass parameters`

Comment: I found that parameter too and even tried it earlier, no changes.

Comment: Actually no, now I get error `Server error!` `The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.`